# Entity Relationship diagrams

Tags: erd

A patient has two subtypes inpatient and outpatient.

I understand that inpatient and outpatient are weak entities.

How can I connect the patient entity with both inpatient entity and outpatient entity.

Answer (score 0):

it is a little different depending on the ER-diagram tool.

sub-entity is all connect to parent entity

I will add several pictures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: search 'subtype' on google images and find the relevant type what you use.

Comment: Thank you. neatly explained